Is a chemical test of Special Relativity possible by monitoring rates of chemical reaction?
Is there is a suitable chemical reaction that could be used to test Special Relativity (via a variant of the twins "paradox"). I'm not concerned with the physics here just finding a suitable chemical reaction and conditions that could be monitored with sufficient accuracy.
The basic set up would involve two carefully controlled identical sets of experimental apparatus. Set A remaining unaccelerated and an set B being accelerated to high speed, left at high speed for a considerable period, then being decelerated and the process reversed to bring A and B back together again at rest where the rate of reaction in A and B could be compared.
A suitable reaction would need to take years to go to completion
It would need to be unaffected by modest accelerations (0.1-1g)
The rate of reaction would need to be easy to measure
The rate of reaction would need to be measurable to a high degree of accuracy. (to within at least 1 in a million, the greater the better).
Just to repeat I really do not want to get into any discussion of the physics of Special Relativity or the the twins paradox here, just the chemistry of a possible test.

This cannot be answered within chemistry and is totally a physics question. Technically, as long as you can perform the experiments with sufficient accuracy, any reaction would suffice. When physicists talk about the nature of spacetime, we f--king mean it. There can be no experiment that violates what GR says that the time should be, at least until quantum gravity comes up with a test.

Forget about using low-energy chemical processes for something like this. Something involving higher energy density, like let us say subatomic particles streaming at near the speed of light, would work a little better.

One doesn't even need a reaction. Electrons get relativistic in heavier atoms, resulting for example in the color of gold.

@naturallyInconsistent no this is totally a question concerning chemistry. Any reaction would not suffice as many reactions occur too quickly or have all manner of side reactions or even more importantly (as you suggest ) cannot be determined with sufficient accuracy.

@Mithoron One absolutely does need a reaction in order to answer this question.

One can tell you that trying to reinvent an atomic clock isn't a good idea.

We have been there, done that — but not with chemical reactions, which are inherently too low in energy relative to the mass of material involved to directly show relativistic time dilation. Instead, physicists demonstrate it with muon decay.
Muons are supposed to decay with a half-life of 1.56 microseconds (sometimes the mean lifetime of about 2.2 microseconds is quoted, but with exponential decay the half-life is only about 69% of the mean lifetime). Muons generated by cosmic rays, traveling near the speed of light, should take about four times that half-life to reach the ground from 2000 meters above. So we should see only about 1/16 the amount of muons at ground level versus 2000 meters above. But the experimentally observed ratio is closer to one-half because (in our reference frame) the decay is relativistically time-dilated. See https://www.fizzics.org/relativity-and-muon-decay/.

Isn't it 2.2 microsecond? And it's not all that "chemical" example. Relativistic effects sure happen in atoms too.

This is a chemistry question!

The muon case is well known, sensitive and accurate, but it is explicitly not what the OP  asked for.

But, for the reason I give, I assume a chemical reaction is not going to work!

That is correct. And that would be the answer, more or less verbose.

The readers of the topic must consider that the scenario is specific in involving a chemical reaction. So other SR confirmations, even if much more sensitive and accurate, do not apply.
Chemical reactions are generally unsuitable for such a SR verification. They are too sensitive to reaction conditions and their outcome cannot be determined with sufficient accuracy.
Reaction rates of chemical reactions typically increase 2-4 times with $T$ increase by $\pu{10 K}$.
If I take 2 times as less sensitive case, then speed e.g. $\pu{70 km/s}$ would slow down reaction the same way as cooling by about $\pu{400 nK}$. Keeping temperature constant within even smaller margins is unreal for such high speeds. For low speeds, the temperature change equivalent would be much smaller.
Another big source of error is the initial condition like dosing the reactants.
Another big source of error would be determining the reaction quotient (extent). Measurements with relative accuracy better than 0.0001 are rare.
As the result, SR effect would be hidden in errors of measurement.
OTOH, the most sensitive atomic or ion clocks can detect motion about $\pu{10 m/s}$ or less.

Thank you I fear you are correct and this might not be possible.

My answer is in effect complementary to this one. This answer explains why chemical reactions can't work to directly reveal SR time dilation; mine describes an experimebtal alternative that does.

@OscarLanzi I do not doubt that it is true. What I have meant in my other comment was that IMHO Slarty is aware about these alternatives.
